# Qt application crashing immediately without debugging info. How do I track down the problem?

Tags: qt, crash

I run an Qt app I've built:

```
./App
Segmentation fault
```

I run it with strace:

```
strace ./App
execve("./App", ["./App"], [/* 27 vars */]) = 0
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Process 868 detached
```

Again, no useful info.

I run it with gdb:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/test/App
Reading symbols from shared object read from target memory...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded system supplied DSO at 0xffffe000

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000001 in ?? ()
```

Again, nothing.

I run it with valgrind:

```
==948== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==948==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x0
==948==    at 0x1: (within /root/test/App)
```

Even if I put in debugging symbols, it doesn't give any more useful info. ldd shows all libraries being linked properly.

Is there any other way I can find out what's wrong?  I can't even do standard printf, cout, etc debugging.  The executable doesn't even seem to start running at all.

I rebuilt with symbols, and tried the suggestion below

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x45470
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/test/App
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80045470
Reading symbols from shared object read from target memory...done.
Loaded system supplied DSO at 0xffffe000

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000001 in ?? ()
```

I checked for static initializers and I don't seem to have any.

Yep, I tried printf, cout, etc.  It doesn't even make it into the main routine, so I'm looking for problems with static initializers in link libraries, adding them in one-by-one.  I'm not getting any stack traces either.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint at main (break main) before executing 'run' in gdb and step through each line, if possible.

Comment: Could it be that there are static initializers in one of the linked libraries. Definitely sounds like something askew with libc and/or static initializers due to maybe bad linkage (differing architecture or 32/64-bit differences maybe, not sure how such a thing would happen though).

Comment: Did you try to get a backtrace from gdb?

Comment: Thanks, everyone, it appears to have been a static initializer in boost::filesystem.  I removed the reference and replaced it with standard code, and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it through [strace](http://sourceforge.net/projects/strace/), it might give you at least some hints what happens before the program crashes. Also, does a backtrace in gdb not work?